# Handlebars template not displaying the data, nor giving any error

Tags: javascript, ajax, handlebars.js

```
////////////////////////////////////
//  Function to append projects  //
//////////////////////////////////

function appendProjects(data) {
    var templateScript = document.getElementById('projects').innerHTML;
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
    var compiledTemplate = theTemplate(data);
    document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = compiledTemplate;
}

///////////////////////////////////////
// Function to append projects list //
/////////////////////////////////////

function appendList(data) {
    var templateScript = document.getElementById('list').innerHTML;
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
    var compiledTemplate = theTemplate(data);
    document.getElementById('left').innerHTML = compiledTemplate;
}

/////////////////////////////////
//  AJAX function             //
///////////////////////////////

function pullData() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "/assets/data/projects.json", true);
    function onReadyStateChange() {
        if(request.readyState === 4) {
            if(request.status >= 200 & request.status <= 400) {
                var data = request.responseText;
                console.log(data);
                appendProjects(data);
                appendList(data);
            }
        }
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChange;
    request.send();
}
```

and my Handlebars template is

```
<script type="x-handlebars-template" id="projects">
    {{#each this}}
    <img src="{{img}}" class="{{class}}">
    <p class="{{class}}" id="{{pid}}">{{description}}</p>
    <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">
        <button class="try {{class}}" style="max-width: 49%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">Try It</button>
    </a>
    <a href="{{source}}" target="_blank">
        <button class="{{class}} try" style="max-width: 49%; float: right; margin-left: 1%;"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i> Code</button>
    </a>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

and this is the sample data

```
[
     {
        "name": "Doinmin",
        "img": "assets/img/doinmin.png",
        "description": "This project started as a basic to-do app, but along the way I turned it into something that I use while practicing a musical instrument. The app can be used to deal with big tasks that can be broken down into smaller tasks, with each task being dealt
                with for a certain amount of time. It prevents you from getting overwhelmed. The app is built using HTML5, CSS3, and jQuery. <br>The app is not fit for android based browsers because the alarm function doesn't work in android browsers, it is not allowed.
                You may try the app or look up the source code on GitHub.",
        "url": "http://doinmin.com/",
        "source": "https://github.com/relentless-coder/Doinmin",
        "class": "doin",
        "pid": "dpara",
        "lid": "doin"
    },
     {
        "name": "Weather Clock",
        "img": "assets/img/weather.png",
        "description": "I built this app to practice CSS3 animations and improve skills in Angular.js. The app has clock, alarm clock, and weather functionality. This is an ongoing project, so more features will added in the future.<br> The app uses Angular.js, HTML, and
                CSS3. I have used Angular.js controllers and services for the functionality, transform animations, and media queries to change the layout for responsive design. You may try the app or look up the source code on GitHub.",
        "url": "weather.html",
        "source": "https://github.com/relentless-coder/weather",
        "class": "weather",
        "pid": "wpara",
        "lid": "weather"
    }
]
```

my template isn't displaying any data. I am not getting any error either.
I am guessing it has something to do with the data that I've provided, but I tried explicitly parsing it to JSON, but that gave me an error

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 331
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onReadyStateChange (work.js:63)
```

Comment: Have you validated your JSON?  [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @SandeepNayak I fixed my JSON, but the template script with id 'projects` is not working. It is not displaying any data.

Comment: you should pass object to the template. So you need to parse JSON and then pass it to the template

Answer (score 0):

Your problem related to your JSON. It contains from some kind of irregular characters. Just try to replace it with following content:

```
[
     {
        "name": "Doinmin",
        "img": "assets/img/doinmin.png",
        "description": "This project started as a basic to-do app, but along the way I turned it into something that I use while practicing a musical instrument. The app can be used to deal with big tasks that can be broken down into smaller tasks, with each task being dealt with for a certain amount of time. It prevents you from getting overwhelmed. The app is built using HTML5, CSS3, and jQuery. <br>The app is not fit for android based browsers because the alarm function doesn't work in android browsers, it is not allowed. You may try the app or look up the source code on GitHub.",
        "url": "http://doinmin.com/",
        "source": "https://github.com/relentless-coder/Doinmin",
        "class": "doin",
        "pid": "dpara",
        "lid": "doin"
    },
     {
        "name": "Weather Clock",
        "img": "assets/img/weather.png",
        "description": "I built this app to practice CSS3 animations and improve skills in Angular.js. The app has clock, alarm clock, and weather functionality. This is an ongoing project, so more features will added in the future.<br> The app uses Angular.js, HTML, and CSS3. I have used Angular.js controllers and services for the functionality, transform animations, and media queries to change the layout for responsive design. You may try the app or look up the source code on GitHub.",
        "url": "weather.html",
        "source": "https://github.com/relentless-coder/weather",
        "class": "weather",
        "pid": "wpara",
        "lid": "weather"
    }
]
```

To solve you problem first of all you need to clean up your data.
Try to replace

```
var data = request.responseText;
```

With

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request.responseText));
```

Looks like it should help in your case

Comment: what I had provided is a sample of my data. I can't post the whole data because it is in large amount. I have it as an array of objects, and I have checked nothing is wrong with the data. also, the solution didn't help